# How can i return all values from for loop in python3 mongodb query

Tags: python, jquery, mongodb, find, return

I have a function that queries  a mongodb collection

```
def checkDb():
    signals =  mydb['collection']
    findInMongo =  signals.find({}, {'_id': False})
    for x in findInMongo:
        return x
```

I want to return everything from the collection without printing it to the console. When I run the above code I get one result:

```
{'Date': testvalue, 'Open': testvalue, 'High': testvalue, 'Low': testvalue, 'Close': testvalue, 'Volume':testvalue}
```

When I run

```
def checkDb():
    signals =  mydb['collection']
    findInMongo =  signals.find({}, {'_id': False})
    for x in findInMongo:
        print(x)
```

I get every  single document from my collection, which is what i want.
How can i make the code return every single document instead of using `print`?

Comment: What about, omit the loop, and `return list(findInMongo)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `return`, when you probably want `yield`:

```py
def checkDb():
    signals =  mydb['collection']
    findInMongo =  signals.find({}, {'_id': False})
    for x in findInMongo:
        return x # This will exit after the first result
```

`return` exits the function, it literally returns a value from the function, exiting scope. `yield` on the other hand, will keep producing values until the iterator is exhausted (or `findInMongo` has no more elements in the `for` loop).

Instead, do

```py
def checkDb():
    signals =  mydb['collection']
    findInMongo =  signals.find({}, {'_id': False})
    for x in findInMongo:
        yield x

# which allows you to do
vals = list(checkDb())
```

Because `checkDb()` is now an iterator (or more specifically, a generator). Later versions of python3 also introduced the nice-looking `yield from` syntax

```py
def checkDb():
    signals =  mydb['collection']
    findInMongo =  signals.find({}, {'_id': False})
    yield from findInMongo # yield from a collection directly
```

Or, you could just return `findInMongo` if that is an iterator

```py
def checkDb():
    signals =  mydb['collection']
    findInMongo =  signals.find({}, {'_id': False})
    return findInMongo # return the iterator directly
```

All of these will support `list(checkDb())` or `[x for x in checkDb()]` syntax

Comment: Thank you makes sense and both  code examples worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: Good to hear, if the answer worked for you, feel free to accept it. If you need any additional clarification or this doesn't answer your question, you can suggest an edit. Happy coding!